# How to easily maintain the same axis scale for two histograms

Tags: r, ggplot2, gridextra

Saw some similar code, but I was curious if this was possible with the "gridExtra" package. I want to show these on the same scale of the x and the y axis. Need to do this for boxplots as well. Is there an easier way to do this with grid.arrange()?

[image]

```
library(tidyverse)
library(gridExtra)

#Subset of Data
za <- structure(list(sodium = c(1.77, 1.79, 1.63, 1.61, 1.64, 1.65, 
1.58, 1.75, 1.71, 1.66), cal = c(4.93, 4.84, 4.95, 4.74, 4.67, 
4.67, 4.63, 4.72, 4.93, 4.95)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -10L))

#Histogram
sodHist <- ggplot(data = za, mapping = aes(x = sodium)) +
  geom_histogram(fill = "royalblue1", color = "white") +
  ggtitle("Sodium Distribution of Pizzas")

calHist <- ggplot(data = za, mapping = aes(x = cal)) +
  geom_histogram(fill = "limegreen", color = "white") +
  ggtitle("Calorie Distribution of Pizzas")

grid.arrange(sodHist,calHist, ncol = 2)
```

Comment: Would it be better to facet them? That by default preserves the axes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are feeding two grobs into `grid.arrange` with the axes already set. The cleanest way to make the y axes equal is probably to "crack open" the underlying ggplots and make their axes equal internally:

```r
grid.arrange.equal <- function(plotA, plotB, ...)
{
  A <- ggplot_build(plotA)
  B <- ggplot_build(plotB)
  if(A$layout$panel_scales_y[[1]]$range$range[2] > B$layout$panel_scales_y[[1]]$range$range[2])
  B$layout$coord$limits$y <- A$layout$panel_scales_y[[1]]$range$range
  else
  A$layout$coord$limits$y <- B$layout$panel_scales_y[[1]]$range$range

  grid.arrange(A$plot, B$plot, ...)
}
```

So now you can just do:

```
grid.arrange.equal(calHist, sodHist, ncol=2)
```

The data in your example is a bit short to give nice histograms, but you get the idea:

[image]

With more realistic dummy data:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I would go with facets as[r2evans](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3358272/r2evans) suggests

```
za %>% 
  mutate(num = row_number()) %>% # add rownumbers to allow the pivoting
  pivot_longer(-num, names_to = "atom", values_to = "val") %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = val, col = atom, fill = atom)) +
  geom_histogram() +
  facet_wrap(~atom)
```